# Ionic 2 - How to reach a component from inside a directive?

Tags: components, ionic2, directive, viewchild

I'm trying to build a directive to display a custom numpad when 
the control (input) on which the directive is applied is clicked.
I'm Working on Ionic 2 RC5.

myPage.html

> ```
> <ion-content>
>   <ion-item>
>       <ion-label stacked>Label</ion-label>
>       <ion-input dirNumpad type="text" [(ngModel)]="myField"></ion-input>
>   </ion-item>
> </ion-content>
> <ion-footer>
>   <numpad #idNumpad hidden></numpad>
> </ion-footer>
> ```

The Numpad component is in the DOM, at the bottom of the page.

dirNumpad.ts

> ```
> import { Directive, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
> import { Numpad } from '../../components/numpad/numpad';
> @Directive({
>   selector: '[dirNumpad]',            // Attribute selector
>   host: {
>       '(click)':          'onClick()'
>   }
> })
> export class DirNumpad {
>   @ViewChild('idNumpad') numpad: Numpad;
>   constructor( private el:    ElementRef ) {
>   }
>   onClick() {
>       this.showNumpad();
>   }
>   showNumpad() {
>       console.log(this.numpad);   => undefined
>       this.numpad.show();     => error: show property does not exist on undefined
>   }
> }
> ```

numpad.html

> `<div class="numpad" style="position:absolute; top:auto; left:0;
>   right:0; bottom:0; height:150px;">My Numpad</div>`

numpad.ts

> ```
> import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
> @Component({
>   selector: 'numpad',
>   templateUrl: 'numpad.html'
> })
> export class Numpad {
>   constructor() {}
> }
> ```

My problem: I can not reach the numpad component from inside the directive through ViewChild.
console.log(this.numpad) always returns "undefined"!
I need it to show the numpad only if user clicks on the input on which the directive is applied...

What am I doing wrong?
I'm stucked with this problem, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewChild only applies to the children items of the item. Since the component is not a child in any way of the directive but rather a sibling it cant be received in ViewChild.

You can pass it as part of an input

Declare an input in your component

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Numpad } from '../../components/numpad/numpad';
@Directive({
  selector: '[dirNumpad]',            // Attribute selector
  host: {
      '(click)':          'onClick()'
  }
})
export class DirNumpad {
  @Input('numpad') numpad: Numpad;
  constructor( private el:    ElementRef ) {
  }
  onClick() {
      this.showNumpad();
  }
  showNumpad() {
      console.log(this.numpad);   => undefined
      this.numpad.show();     => error: show property does not exist on undefined
  }
}
```

and set it in your html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Label</ion-label>
      <ion-input dirNumpad [numpad]="idNumpad" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myField"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <numpad #idNumpad hidden></numpad>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.
I had some doubts about Viewchild use in this particular case...
And I didn't know that the directive could get the input from control as easy as you showed to me.
However, I do not really understand why it works.
I must dive deeper in directives functionning...